# How to remove the green line at the bottom of assets video in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, video, assets

Whenever I play a video from assets in Flutter Application (debug and release mode), it shows green a line at the bottom of video.

The following image represents the problem:

[image: image of video]

here is my flutter doctor output:
[image]

How do I remove that? Did I miss something? Here is my code:

```
body: Center(
      child: _controller.value.initialized
          ? AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            )
          : Container(),
    ),
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Sajjad,
   Can you include some screenshots as well in your question. Additional details like which operating system / IDE / plugins you are using will be helpful for understanding your issue.

Comment: I have the same issue with video player and Chewie